# How to copy S3 objects across accounts through a function call?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to create a function which then my client can call to copy files from a source S3 bucket in account A to a destination S3 bucket in account B.

I came across several resources suggesting to setup IAM roles and ACLs, however, I noticed that this would always automatically sync the two buckets as opposed to when the user wants it to.

How do I create this functionality in such a way that files are copied only when the user makes the call and not automatically whenever an event occurs within the source bucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up IAM or ACL will **not** sync the S3 buckets. They're just permissions to copy. You need to set up a mechanism to do the copying. If it's a Lambda function with an S3 trigger, then what you're saying is true and it will sync all the files.

If you need to make it manual, you can use that code (with some changes) to achieve the same. For instance, you can have a Lambda function expecting the source and target buckets as the input and it can call the S3 API to do the copying. The biggest issue is it will timeout if you have a lot of files to copy.

Then you can have this in a container and run an ECS container to trigger the code. Then you can have a small Lambda function or even a scheduled trigger to start the ECS instance.

You can also run the code manually on your local machine if that's feasible.

**Summary**:
Having IAM and ACL setup doesn't mean it will automatically copy. You must need a compute instance to trigger the actual copying.